# Julia add DateTime to Time or set component

Tags: julia

```
time = Time(9, 00, 00)
dateTime = Dates.now()
```

How can I set the time component of dateTime to time?  Simply adding them does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
DateTime(Date(dateTime), time)
```

Comment: Just noting that contrary to the question, adding does also work (as long as you convert to `Date` first), e.g. `Date(dateTime) + time`